# NodeJS simple script keeps increasing memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks

I recently found myself debugging a small-medium nodejs app which keeps increasing its memory when I am debugging it using chrome debug tools. Memory keeps increasing a little everytime I take a snapshot, ~1mb/15minutes, but I cannot find any memory leak at all.

I just cut it down to this bunch of code and memory keeps increasing as well. What is going on?

```js
(async () => {
  while (true) {
    await fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/ping");
    await sleep(3000);
  }
})();
```

Sleep function is just a new Promise resolve with setTimeout.

[image: snapshot 9]
[image: snapshot 6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this also increase the memory?

```
const pingIt = () => fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/ping")
.then(() => setTimeout(pingIt,3000))
```

Comment: Hey, yes, it does too :(

Comment: Weirdness. Also in another browser? And in incognito mode?

Comment: Seems in incognito it doesn't, weird.

Comment: You could have an internet security plugin that is the problem

Comment: @BillyMango So you found it?